# Pandas read_csv usecols accepting non-existent column names

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to make Pandas.[read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) raise an error if a column specified in usecols are not found in the input file? E.g. in the following example, I'd like Pandas to raise an exception since there's no column called "hello" in the input-file:

```
import pandas as pd

# Write dummy-data
csv = r"""col1,col2,col3
one,two,three"""
with open("data.csv", "w") as out:
    out.write(csv)

# Read dummy-data to DF
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", usecols=["col1", "col2", "hello"])
print df.to_string(index=False)
```

Output:

```
col1 col2 col3
one  two  NaN
```

So Pandas reads the third column name in the file ("col3") and fills it with NaNs, rather than raising an error that "hello" doesn't exist. I'd like to get notified upon reading the file, rather than having to validate file content after reading it into memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could just read the header and test if all expected column names are present using `isin`:

```
In [10]:
import io
csv = r"""col1,col2,col3
one,two,three"""
# Read dummy-data to DF
cols=["col1", "col2", "hello"]
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv), usecols=cols, nrows=0)
df.columns.isin(cols)

Out[10]:
array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

You can use `all` to test if all cols are present:

```
In [11]:
df.columns.isin(cols).all()

Out[11]:
False
```

additionally you can invert the mask to find the missing col:

```
In [18]:
np.array(cols)[~df.columns.isin(cols)]

Out[18]:
array(['hello'], 
      dtype='<U5')
```

You can put this logic in a user func to return you a list of any missing column names:

```
def missingCol(cols, path):
    read_cols = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=cols, nrows=0).columns
    return np.array(cols)[~read_cols.isin(cols)].tolist()
```

Comment: The steps in "In [10]" do not work since pd.read_csv will throw a ValueError and variable df will not exist.

Comment: To avoid the ValueError use `usecols=lambda x: x in cols`